# Inserting formula through VBA in "A1" reference style

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I insert this formula through VBA,

```
Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(A2;5)"
```

But the formula which gets inserted ends up with apostrophes.

```
=LEFT('A2';5)
```

This works perfectly with the R1C1 notation, but not with the A1 type.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.Formula` instead of `.FormulaR1C1` solved the problem.

```
Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=LEFT(A2;5)"
```